# Number of real roots for $x^4+5|x^3|+3x^2+20|x|+10=0$ are?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Number of real roots for $x^4+5|x^3|+3x^2+20|x|+10=0$ are ?

****Approach:-****

I used **Descarte's rule of signs** to get an idea of how many real roots does a polynomial equation have, so I thought of making 2 cases for x>0 and x<0

**Case 1:- when x>0**

f(x)=$x^4+5x^3+3x^2+20x+10=0$

now there are 0 sign changes here so that means 0 positive real roots

now I will try for f(-x) = $x^4-5x^3+3x^2-20x+10=0$

here we have 4 sign changes indicating at most there can be 4 negative real roots, so I tabulated the possibilities which we can get

1. 4 negative real roots, 0 imaginary roots
2. 2 negative real roots , 2 imaginary roots
3. 4 imaginary roots

Now I did same procedure for **Case 2:- when x<0**

f(x)=$x^4-5x^3+3x^2-20x+10=0$

here we have 4 sign changes which means we can have at most 4 positive real roots

f(-x)=$x^4+5x^3+3x^2+20x+10=0$

here 0 sign changes so no negative real roots possible

so the possibilities from this case would be:-

1. 4 positive real roots, 0 imaginary roots
2. 2 positive real roots , 2 imaginary roots
3. 4 imaginary roots

how to proceed from here (using this method) ?

Comment: Look at your cases.  If $x>0$ then your cases with real roots have negative real roots only.  A contradiction.  Similarly for the other case.  Note:  the Rule of Signs is not a good method to use on this problem.

Comment: As Aqua suggested notice that $P(x)=P(|x|)$ so the signs are just +++++, but if $x$ solution, so is $-x$...

Comment: yeah @lulu agreed with you, can you tell me do I need to make separate cases for x>0 and x<0, or if I prove contradiction in just one case , it would be enough to comment that it has 0 roots by Descarte's rule ?

Answer (score 6):

There is no real root of this equation since the function on left have only nonnegative terms and the last one is strictly positive, so their sum can never be $0$ (for real $x$).

Comment: Thanks for the answer , can you let me know how can this be solved using Descartes rule of signs too ? am I doing it right ?

Comment: Replace $x$ by $t^2$ in the polynomial  Then you can remove the absolute values.  There are zero sign changes, so by Descartes Rule of Signs, there are no positive roots.   Replace $t$ by $-t$ and there are still no sign changes because all nonzero terms are of even degree.  So there are no negative root.

Comment: Why not $|x|$ with $t$? @B.Goddard

Comment: What stops $t$ from being negative then? @Aqua

Comment: @B.Goddard if we replace x by $t^2$ , then in the case of x as negative , won't the condition be violated , of a square being a negative number ?

Comment: @Fin27  That's why there are two cases.

Comment: @B.Goddard can you tell me do I need to make separate cases for x>0 and x<0, or if I prove contradiction in just one case , would it be enough to comment that it has 0 real roots by Descarte's rule ?